# How to replace value using python format function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, string.format

I have these data and I want to write a python program to replace the value from csv.
My csv has below data:

```
name,studentno
abc,student1
xyz,student2
rty,student3
wer,student4
```

Code:

```
mystring= "Test {} value : {}"

print (my_string.format(column1value from csv, column2value from csv))
```

How can I loop through csv and put the column values? Please help. I need Output as shown below.
Output:

```
Test abc value : student1
Test xyz value : student2
Test rty value : student3
Test wer value : student4
```

Comment: Is "my_string.format(column1value from csv, column2value from csv)" really your only attempt at code? This does not look anything like valid python syntax...

Comment: Try to figure out how to loop over the lines of a csv and print the values of every column. Once you can do that, your task is very easy. I'm afraid we won't instruct you how to write a `for` loop or open a file, however.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

mystring= "Test {} value : {}"

with open('yourfil.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        mystring.format(row[0], row[1])
```

I think this should work.